# Method(s) to turn a “single equation” problem into a “double equation” problem?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

In the world of Diophantine analysis, there are single equation problems (*e.g.*, “Find all solutions $(x,y)$ such that $x^3=y^2+1$”), double equation problems (*e.g.*, “Find all numbers $p$ such that $p+1$ and $p^2+1$ are both the double of a square”), and problems involving three or more equations which share one or more of the variables.

What, if any, are the principal methods of [non-trivially] “upgrading” one type to a “higher” type? Can every single equation problem be [non-trivally] turned into a multiple-equation problem?

Note: By “non-trivially”, I mean *not* just rational transformations like writing an odd number $x$ as $2u+1$. Rather, I mean taking a single equation which [apparently] provides 'exactly $N$' units of information about the numbers/variables involved and turning it into two or more equations where the total amount of information is greater than '$N$'.

Answer (score 1):

For some single equations, you can in fact split it and solve it as an *intersection of two quadric surfaces*. So you now have *two* equations to solve. But the upside is if there is a rational point, then there may be *infinitely* many.

---

This can be done for,

$$a^4+b^4+c^4 = d^4\tag1$$

as Elkies did in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509526/more-elliptic-curves-for-x4y4z4-1). For example, express the above as,

$$(p + r)^4 + (p - r)^4 + s^4 = q^4\tag2$$
$$2p^4 + 12p^2r^2 + 2r^4 + s^4 = q^4\tag{2b}$$

Then it can be split into two quadrics with extra parameter $m$,

$$-(3 m^2 - 8m + 6) p^2 + 2 (m^2 - 2) p q - 2 m q^2 = (m^2 + 2) r^2\tag3$$
$$ -4 (m^2 - 2) p^2 +    8 m p q + (m^2 - 2) q^2 = (m^2 + 2) s^2\tag4$$

To see the intersection of $(3),(4)$, simply eliminate $m$ between the two [using resultants](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Factor%5BResultant%5B-%283%20m%5E2%20-%208m%20%2B%206%29%20p%5E2%20%2B%202%20%28m%5E2%20-%202%29%20p%20q%20-%20%202%20m%20q%5E2%20-%20%28m%5E2%20%2B%202%29%20r%5E2%2C%20-4%20%28m%5E2%20-%202%29%20p%5E2%20%2B%20%208%20m%20p%20q%20%2B%20%28m%5E2%20-%202%29%20q%5E2%20-%20%28m%5E2%20%2B%202%29%20s%5E2%2C%20m%5D%5D), then factor and one recovers $(2b)$.

---

Similarly, it can also be done for,

$$a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4 = (a+b+c+d)^4$$

as Jacobi and Madden [did here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191316/more-elliptic-curves-for-a4b4c4d4-abcd4).

---

Or for,

$$a^6+b^6+c^6 = d^2$$

as Bremner and Ulas [showed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4633598/4781). But the trick is to find those quadric surfaces which is ***no*** easy feat.